# How to loop through directory files using IF THEN and variables?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, batch-file, cmd, sha256

I have a directory with files and a ControlFile.txt that contains the a list of SHA256 sums for various files. I'm trying to come up with a Batch process to loop through the files in the directory, calculate the SHA256 value of each file, and then compare whether or not the calculated SHA256 exists or not in the ControlFile.txt and branch accordingly.

I've attempted to produce a working script with the following but I believe I'm missing some key elements:

```
for /R . %%f in (*.*)  do (
find /c "(certutil -hashfile "%%f" SHA256 | findstr /V "hash")" ControlFile.txt > NUL
    if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound
        echo "%%f" found
    goto done
    :notfound
        echo "%%f" notfound
    goto done
    :done)
```

I believe I may need to set a variable for the given SHA256 value and use that within the loop to produce the comparative function I'm trying to achieve, but my knowledge with batch files and cmd is limited. Any code advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q74148620.txt"

FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /s /b /a-d "u:\j*" ') DO (
 FOR /f %%y IN ('certutil -hashfile "%%b" SHA256 ^| find /V ":"') do (
  findstr /x "%%y" "%filename1%" > NUL
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   ECHO "%%b" NOT found
  ) ELSE (
   ECHO "%%b" found
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a filemask of `j*` for testing - change to suit.

Simply run the `certutil` routine on each file in turn, filter out any lines that contain `:`, leaving the SHA256 data. Locate that value as `/x` an exact mach to a line in the SHA256 values file. If a match is found, `errorlevel` is set to `0`, non-`0` otherwise, then switch on `errorlevel`.

=== minor revision to **not** include subdirectories ===

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q74148620.txt"

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d') DO (
 FOR /f %%y IN ('certutil -hashfile "%%b" SHA256 ^| find /V ":"') do (
  findstr /x "%%y" "%filename1%" > NUL
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   ECHO "%%b" NOT found
  ) ELSE (
   ECHO "%%b" found
  )
 )
)

POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

The `dir` options `/b` shows the names only (not size, date, etc.), `/s` would scan subdirectories and also generate the filenames with their full path,  and `/a-d` suppresses directory names. `u:\j*` is the start location for the listing; drive `u:`, all files that begin `j` (that was for testing).

The `pushd` command makes the nominated directory current, so the revised `dir` command will scan only that directory for all filenames but no directorynames (since no starting directory and filemask is provided).

The `popd` command returns to the original directory.

Comment: Thank you Mister Magoo! This performs the operations as expected! My only questions is regarding the file qualifiers in the first IN clause ('dir /s /b /a-d "u:\j*" ') . I am ignorant on the scope of these, could you provide some explanation? For my usecase my files may have numbers within their filenames and I want to be certain that subdirectories and files in those subdirectories are excluded from processing. Testing it out, it looks like subdirectory files are included

Comment: Is the fact that the filenames contain digits relevant? There is no processing here that treats filenames containing digits differently from thos not containing digits.

Comment: Hi Magoo, this is my speaking from a point of ignorance here. I am not familiar with Batch operators so I am hoping to borrow some of your understanding. I misinterpret the  clauses within the IN parentheses with the number characters. 

Is there a way to exclude subdirectories within the IN clause statement? I would like to apply these operations on to the designated directory if possible.

Comment: The entry in the parentheses is a simple `dir` command. Documentation : `dir /?` at the prompt. The `/s` includes subdirectories in the listing. If you omit the `/s`, the dir will only scan the current directory, unless the filemask is directly preceded by a directoryname\ (eg. c:\mydirectory\*.jpg - scan `mydirectory` on C: for all `.jpg` files.) It's easier to switch to the required directory and simply omit mentioning the directory in the `dir` command. This is what I have shown in the second listing.